# Finding type hint name of dataclass attributes

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass with typed attributes, using types I defined as seen below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

PositiveFloatType = NewType("PositiveFloat", float)

@dataclass(init=False, frozen=True)
class Foo:
    bar: PositiveFloatType = 1
```

On runtime, I'd like to get to the type of Foo.bar. I.e., I'd like to find all attributes of class Foo, and know their type names, in case of Foo.bar - get "PositiveFloatType".

I tried using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to no avail. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `dataclasses` module provides the [`fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) function for:

```
from dataclasses import fields

for f in fields(Foo):
    print(f.name, f.type.__name__)
```

Comment: Just a warning, `f.type` will be a string if you use `from __future__ import annotations` anywhere.

Comment: Not *anywhere*, but *within that file that defines the dataclass*. And yes, since that will be the default behaviour sometime soonish, your code should expect that.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, taking into account the fact that `f.type` can be a string, and I assume you actually want the concrete class object.

```py
from typing import Any, Type, get_type_hints

def get_field_type(data_class: Type[Any], field_name: str) -> Type[Any]:
   return get_type_hints(data_class)[field_name]
```